# Do not auto hide Toolbar in Project Web App

Tags: microsoft

Is there a way I can pin the toolbar of Microsoft Project Web App — highlighted in the image blow with a red rectangle surrounding it — for it not to auto hide itself?

[image]

Comment: did you try double-clicking the timesheet tab?

Comment: Yes, but it disappears after I navigate among time sheets using Previous & Next buttons!